# how to uniquely identify records without their IDs being shown?

Tags: php, mysql

In the website I'm designing the admin list page shows fields such as Name, Email, Username and Status(whether active or inactive users). My database has a table called **admin**. The fields are *iAdminId, vFirstName, vLastName, vEmail, vUserName, vPassword, vFromIP, vFromIP, dLastLogin, and eStatus*.

In the equivalent  PHP page (the admin list page) I need to add a *delete* button. Check boxes are present with each row. The number of rows that an administrator chooses will be deleted (after confirmation, of course) once he/she clicks on *Delete* button. My problem is since I havent mentioned the *iAdminId* field in my listing page how do I uniquely identify each record?

My javscript code for deletion is:

```
function deleteRecord()
{
    var count = getCount();
    if(count == 0)
    {
      alert("Please enter some records for deletion first!!");
    }
    else
    {
      var c = confirm("Do you wish to delete?");
      if(c==true)
      {
        document.frm.mode.value="Delete";
        document.frm.submit();
      }
      else
      {
        alert("You had wrongly selected 'Delete' option!!");
      }
    }

  }
```

getCount returns the number of selected records.
And PHP code is

```
if($mode=="Delete")
{
    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['ch']);$i++)
    {
      $delete = "DELETE FROM admin WHERE Name = '".$_POST["ch"][$i]."'";
      $result = mysql_query($delete);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mind having this ID visible in the client-side source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided the email is unique to each user and you have checks to ensure this uniqueness, it can be used else, there is no foolproof way to do this. The only way is to place the id in the listing. 
This is the single unique identifier of each row since using a combination of any of the colums can be repeated.
Another option is to create a composite primary key across two of the fields mentioned or a unique key on the email field.

Eg. To ensure that the email is unique or combinations of first name and surname is unique.

Comment: Thanks a lot.May be that is the only available way. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I would set the value (sometimes people use the name or ID attribute of the element) of the checkbox equal to "admin_n" or "user_n" where n = id. When the form is submitted after pressing delete you can parse that name to pull the id out and processing it that way.

This of course will give out the ID of the user in the source but this isnt really an issue unless you've got crazy security holes in your code..